How to use a custom class App-wid in celery?
As Celery documentation indicates, assume there is a custom class called DatabaseTask.
from celery import Task

class DatabaseTask(Task):
    _db = None

    @property
    def db(self):
        if self._db is None:
            self._db = Database.connect()
        return self._db

This custom class can be passed in Celery app when instantiating the app.
app = Celery('tasks', task_cls=DatabaseTask)

Now, how to use db property in tasks that've been declared using the decorator syntax within the app. For example, How can I use db property in collect_data task?
@app.task
def collect_data():
    #
    # 


you can access the db by self object which is an instance of the DatabaseTask. This instance is automatically passed to tasks defined using the decorator. as show here in the documentation https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#per-task-usage
